# CanJS click event triggered multiple times

Tags: canjs

I am using CanJS 1.1. I have a can control under which I have putted its event like "'.submit click'", now when ever I make a new object multiple times of this control on the page which is not refreshed, my event get triggered multiple times.

I have tried unbinding this when I am doing loadView with can.unbind, but by this also it's not working for me.

can anybody help me with this.

Answer (score 0):

I got that working by killing the old instance with destroy() function. For example

```
if(this.options.objRecoverPwd) {
    this.options.objRecoverPwd.destroy();
}
```

Comment: Yes. If the element is not removed via jQuery or `can.remove` you have to call `destroy` manually to unbind old Controls.